# Need a Joomla! component "reminder by mail"

Tags: joomla, cron, components, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I need a component for Joomla 2.5 to remind people about this website in certain time.

On frontend will be the form:

Remind me about this website on:

"email field"

|dd| |mm| |yyyy| / (date selector)

| remind |

So the component should create a cronjob on this date to send an email. Can you advice something, please? Or suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to store a list of emails and dates in some table.

Cronjobs are outside of Joomla's domain and may not be set by Joomla.
So you would typically provide two solutions to your users:

1. Create a frontend task that performs the mailing: a dedicated controller/task in a custom component usually, something you would invoke with

   index.php?option=your_component&task=cron

   Echo the correct invocation string and ask your user to schedule it as appropriate.
2. Run a check in a plugin, so after rendering is complete you can perform your additional tasks.  There will be no cronjobs since it will be run by Joomla itself on each site visit. You want to make sure your plugin doesn't invoke the function too often or it will kill the site.